# Format user inputed currency

Tags: c#, .net, windows, console, console.readline

Here's my problem, I'm trying to format a `{"C:O"}` into a `console.readline` but I'm getting a method name expected error. here's what I have now:

```
money = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()(string.Format("{O:C}")));
```

Comment: In which format user inputs a data into the console? `{C:0}` is a format for string data type and does not make sense for a double/decimal.

Comment: @sll Notice that they're trying to call the return value of `Console.ReadLine()`. Unless that's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the syntax errors, you should generally use [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) to represent money, since many operations on [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) can result in round-off errors.

I'd recommend something like this:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
decimal money = decimal.Parse(input);
```

Or in one line:

```
decimal money = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

But `Parse` will throw an exception if given invalid input (e.g. `"foo"`). You might want to use [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) to be a bit safer:

```
decimal money;
if (!decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out money))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
}
```